# Issue with creating an empty video and adding images using FFmpeg in C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a C# project where I need to create an empty video file and then add images to it using FFmpeg. However, the code I have implemented doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Here's the code snippet I have:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VideoProcessingApp
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private bool render = false;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo createVideoInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                Arguments = $"-f lavfi -i nullsrc -t 10 -s {pictureBox2.Width}x{pictureBox2.Height} -r 30 -c:v libx264 output.mp4",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (Process createVideoProcess = new Process())
            {
                createVideoProcess.StartInfo = createVideoInfo;
                createVideoProcess.Start();

                render = true;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        if (!render)
                            break;

                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                        {
                            bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
                        }));

                        while (bmp == pictureBox1.Image)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }

                        bmp.Save("a.jpg");

                        ProcessStartInfo addImageInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                            Arguments = $"-i output.mp4 -i a.jpg -filter_complex \"overlay=10:10\" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f mp4 -",
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            RedirectStandardError = true,
                            RedirectStandardInput = true,
                            CreateNoWindow = true
                        };

                        using (Process addImageProcess = new Process())
                        {
                            addImageProcess.StartInfo = addImageInfo;
                            addImageProcess.Start();

                            addImageProcess.WaitForExit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            File.Delete("a.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, I'm attempting to create an empty video by executing an FFmpeg command to generate a nullsrc video. Then, I'm using a loop to capture images from a PictureBox control and overlay them onto the video using FFmpeg.

The issue I'm facing is that the video is not being created at all. I have verified that FFmpeg is installed on my system and the paths to the FFmpeg executable are correct.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to dumb down the code until you manage to create an empty video file. Then expand from there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do this via process start instead of using one of the ffmpeg libs?